# jQuery load messes up layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT**

I had my index.css overriding my original header layout. Watch your ID's and classes!

**EDIT**

I'm using jQuery to load my website header and footer sections. Then display them on my index & other pages. However, it seems to resize my header whenever I try to load it. Anyone have any clue as to why that may be? I did some research on this problem but didn't found anything that helps.

Here's the websites it's affecting.

[**INDEX**](http://www.hobbsbearstudios.com)

[**HEADER**](http://www.hobbsbearstudios.com/header.html)

and here's the JSFiddle that has my code in it for the header

[**JSFiddle for Header**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3c50na1/)

and my index code how I'm calling header

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HobbsBear Studios</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/index.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/photobanner.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="_javascript/photobanner.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#header").load("header.html");
                $("#footer").load("footer.html");
            });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <!-- A buncha stuff in the middle --!>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So it is displaying all of the elements just not in the correct layout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this is because the 'Slidy container' that you are using overrides the class names that you are using in your header. You may have to change these class names. Within 2 minutes i found that the following 2 classes were breaking it for you and they are coming from the index.css page.

```
#menu {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 80%; 
 left: 25%; 
 width: 50%; 
 font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif; 
 font-weight: bold; 
}
#logo {
 display: block; 
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto; 
 width: 550px; 
}
```

Thing is you will HAVE to change the ID's either in the content or the header because having more then one of the same ID on a page is not good practice and on some browsers will throw out an error cause it's not 'valid' html structure. ID's are meant to be used to target exact specific elements on a page where as classes are used for targeting multiple elements at once.

Fix this and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, I also had #header and a lot of the same id's. I wanted to completely change the header from what was in index so I basically wiped out the CSS except for what was needed for the SlidyCSS.